# Apache2 mod_rewrite + userdir

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, rewrite

I have an Ubuntu Server (web) with the following configuration

- Version: 13.10
- Installed: Apache2, apache2 utils, php5
- Enabled: rewrite, userdir

#### **Problem**

When I try to use rewrite rules, for example `foo.bar.com/~«user»/page`, I get

> The requested URL `/home/«user»/public_html/page.php` was not found on this server.

As far as I know it is there; when I visit `foo.bar.com/~«user»/page.php`; tada! it is there.

I read all my configurations under `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, `/etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf` but nothing seemed strange to me.

#### *Additional Information*

Permissions for user foder: `drwx r-x r-x`

Permissions for public_html `drwx r-x r-x`

I read I have to provide rewrite base but I really don't see anything strange with the path

What do I miss?

---

*Rewrite Rules:*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Or

```
RewriteRule ^login/?  login.php [L]
```

---

By the way, I tried to move the directory to /var/www and rewrite rules are operational now without 404 errors.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t seem to have a `RewriteBase` set, so it is most likely defaulting to:

```
RewriteBase /
```

So if you want to use it for `userdir` perhaps you should change your rewrite rules in your Apache config file—in `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`—to be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~username/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I wrote in my question; I don't want to provide this information in .htaccess file. Isn't there any place where I can specify that, so every .htaccess file don't include that line.

Comment: Who said this should be placed in an `.htaccess` file?  Put it in the main Apache2 server config for the whole domain & you are done.

Comment: I said I don't know where to place it. Thanks.

Comment: Look in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on ubuntuforums.org:

`RewriteBase /~username/`

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1196217

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I wrote in my question; I don't want to provide this information in .htaccess file. Isn't there any place where I can specify that, so every .htaccess file don't include that line.

Comment: So where do you have these rewrite rules? In userdir.conf? Try to add it in there I guess..